# vim change base of relative path to source to other dir

Tags: vim

I have a local Makefile which simply calls `make -C ..`. As a result I get the output from the compiler with filenames and path to the directory relative to `..`.

Now vim isn't able to get the correct path for quickfix.

Q: How can I set the base path for vim quickfix to `..` ?

My path structure:

```
<bla>/base/proj1/<localMakeFile>
<bla>/base/<globalMakefile>
<bla>/src/source1.cpp
```

I compile inside /base/proj1/

Compiler output for a error is like:
src/source1.cpp|141 col 54| Error: ....

But I am working in
/proj1/ so vim is unable to get the file `src/source1.cpp`

EDIT:
I see that the problem is basically related to the output of gnu make

```
make[4]: Entering directory '<bla>/...'
```

which is not parsed correctly if I use not an English environment. Setting the shell with `export LANG=` all works fine.

Q: Can vim parse also the German output of gnu make?

Comment: You don't give enough details about what you're doing for a more useful answer, but try reading `:h quickfix-directory-stack`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Your comment give me no idea what information is missing. Path strcuture, language, make, vim... what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Appending the localized version with `set errorformat+=<localized version>` should work.

I am not aware that VIM supports it out of the box. After looking at the output of `:set errorformat`, which on my machine is a scary...

```
  errorformat=%*[^"]"%f"%*\D%l: %m,"%f"%*\D%l: %m,%-G%f:%l: (Ea
ch undeclared identifier is reported only once,%-G%f:%l: for ea
ch function it appears in.),%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c:,
%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c\,,%-GIn file included from %f
:%l:%c,%-GIn file included from %f:%l,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:%c,%-G
%*[ ]from %f:%l:,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l\,,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l,%f:%l:
%c:%m,%f(%l):%m,%f:%l:%m,"%f"\, line %l%*\D%c%*[^ ] %m,%D%*\a[%
*\d]: Entering directory %*[`']%f',%X%*\a[%*\d]: Leaving direct
ory %*[`']%f',%D%*\a: Entering directory %*[`']%f',%X%*\a: Leav
ing directory %*[`']%f',%DMaking %*\a in %f,%f|%l| %m
```

...and by changing the output of the build process from

```
make: Entering directory `<directory>`
```

to

```
make: Entering `<directory>`
```

i got it to work by extending `errorformat` like this:

```
:set errorformat+=%D%*\\a:\ Entering\ %*[`']%f'
```

Comment: Your `errorformat` can be set by many things, typically by plugins, compiler sets, or `ftplugin` files.  You need to override it at the right place to have any effect (in particular that's why the OP's description of the problem is useless).  Also, simply appending a localized version won't work, because the order of statements in `errorformat` can actually make a difference.

Comment: @SatoKatsura thanks for the remarks - I set up a scenario similar to the OP's question now, and appending proves to work in this case. Updated the answer accordingly.